# Need help with lighting the scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'm a beginner to Blender and as my first Non-tutorial model, i tried making a Wine Bottle & a Wine Glass.
Well, the modelling went fine but the lighting part is still troubling me.
Can someone please help me with the lighting .

**Here is the reference photo of how I want it to look like(except the cap opener) :** [image: Desired Render Photo]

**And here is my best renders up till now :**

1. [image: Render 1]
2. [image: Render 2]

**I'm also attaching the .blend file :** [image] 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try adding a HDRI for your lighting/reflections. Go to the *World* section of your shading tab and add an *Environment Texture* (not an *Image Texture*).

Blender has some HDRI's at `...2.91/datafiles/studiolights/world`. You can also find plenty more for free online. One of the most popular places is HDRI Haven (https://hdrihaven.com/hdris/):

[image: HDRI]

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked.....

Answer (score 1):

Those pictures are often in multiple exposures of different ligths and then assembled in photoshop to take "the best" parts.

In Blender take planar lights and map them with proper hdr textures of real softboxes, then place planar lights left and right.

You will still need to adjust areas in postprocess to remove things that are unwanted.

Here is my example with three area ligths:[image]